# Using jquery week calendar plugin with Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I find this [Jquery week calendar plugin pretty useful](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar)!. I am just wondering how do i use it with jquery mobile ? or what do i need to in order to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [jQuery Mobile Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/#/jQM-DateBox/demos/calendar/) . Hope this helps

**Edit:** For event Calendar:-

[dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) has a mobile version of the event calendar. You can check the demo [here](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_mobile.shtml) (requires mobile device to view). The code is licensed under GPL.

Comment: well i want to create an event calendar. thats just a datebox plugin

Answer (score 0):

For an Event Calendar, with marked days, multi-day/ week select which is mobile friendly, provides great UX, gesture enabled, customizable and themable give this [Calendar component](http://mobiscroll.com/component/calendar) a try.